# How to create a Javascript function that inspects objects/ function based on property names that will survive minifcation?

Tags: javascript, minify

Suppose I have a function `proxyThrough` like this:

```
function proxyThrough(parentClass, childObjPropertyName, methodName) {
    parentClass.prototype[methodName] = function() {
        this[childObjPropertyName][methodName].apply(this[childObjPropertyName], arguments);
    };
}
```

`childPropertyName` and `methodName` are both strings, and it looks up the functions by name.
I know that this will not survive minification as a result.

How can I get functions like this to survive minification?

---

**Example**

This is what I am doing currently:

```
var BaseView = require('./BaseView');
var FooView = require('./FooView');

function BarView() {
    this._fooView = new FooView();
}

BarView.prototype = Object.create(BaseView.prototype);
BarView.prototype.constructor = BarView;

BarView.prototype.anAction = function() {
    this._barView.anAction.apply(this._barView, arguments);
};

BarView.prototype.anotherAction = function() {
    this._barView.anotherAction.apply(this._barView, arguments);
};
```

This is what I would like to do instead:

```
var BaseView = require('./BaseView');
var FooView = require('./FooView');

function BarView() {
    this._fooView = new FooView();
}

BarView.prototype = Object.create(BaseView.prototype);
BarView.prototype.constructor = BarView;

function proxyThrough(parentClass, childObjPropertyName, methodName) {
    parentClass.prototype[methodName] = function() {
        this[childObjPropertyName][methodName].apply(this[childObjPropertyName], arguments);
    };
}

['anAction', 'anotherAction'].forEach(proxyThrough.bind(null, BarView, '_fooView'));
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if the variable/parameter names are changed as the *values* are used, not the names. Needing to avoid obfuscation is only necessary if operating similar to [AngularJS's Dependency Injection scheme](http://outbottle.com/resolving-angularjs-minimization-obfuscation-issues/).

Comment: Minification needs special workarounds when you need to match variable name to the value of a string.  There is no danger to variable names themselves.

Comment: On the other reading of this task: use an obfuscator which can be controlled, such that the to-be-proxied methods/properties (and thus names of such) are not changed. Once they are changed .. they are changed (before the code even runs) and such names cannot be resolved to the original excepting if there is some retained map.

Comment: @PM77-1 and user2864740 : I am not exactly sure what you mean. So as to be explicit, I have included an SSCCE to illustrate my use case. It does not look like it will survive minification, because I am indeed passing in strings to the `proxyThrough` function.

Comment: Are you sure it won't survive minification? While function parameters are changed often - object fields are usually untouched by minifiers because of how common bracket notation is.

Comment: What minifier are you using? Most minifiers don't rename object properties.

Comment: Rather, **NO** minifier would rename properties. If it did, everything would break horribly. Minifiers rename only variables (including function parameters and function names (actual function names in the case of `function NAME () { }`, not the properties/keys under which the function may be held in an object).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how the minifier works, but if it renames the same property name consistently, you could use a helper function to get the minified property name:

```
function minifiedName(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        return prop;
    }
}

[
   minifiedName({anAction: null}),
   minifiedName({anotherAction: null})
].forEach(proxyThrough.bind(null, BarView, '_fooView'));
```